# WP_Async_Task doesn't appear to be running asynchronously

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have copied the code from [this](https://torquemag.io/2016/01/use-asynchronous-php-wordpress/) example of how to use WP_Async_Task.

But with this modification:

```
add_action( 'wp_async_save_post', 'josh_send_to_api' );
function josh_send_to_api( $id ) {
    wp_mail( 'abc@test.com', date("H:i:s", time() ), $id );

    sleep(25);
    wp_mail( 'abc@test.com', date("H:i:s", time() ), $id );
}
```

The rest of the code is in another file:

```
class Josh_Task extends WP_Async_Task {
    /**
    * Action to use to trigger this task
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $action = 'save_post';

    /**
    * Prepare POST data to send to session that processes the task
    *
    * @param array $data Params from hook
    *
    * @return array
    */
    protected function prepare_data($data){
        return array(
            'post_id' => 5
        );
    }

    /**
    * Run the asynchronous task
    *
    * Calls send_to_api()
    */
    protected function run_action() {
        if( isset( $_POST[ 'post_id' ] ) && 0 < absint( $_POST[ 'post_id' ] ) ) {
        do_action( "wp_async_$this->action", 5 );
        }
    }
}

new Josh_Task();
```

I copied the WP_Async_Task file from [here.](https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task/blob/master/wp-async-task.php)

I am getting the e-mails correctly but it is not asynchronous as expected.
This means that upon saving a post, the page does not reload immediately, but instead takes another 25s for the `sleep(25)` to finish, before reloading.

Does asynchronous not mean 'non-blocking'?
I expected the page to be reloaded roughly the same time as the first e-mail is sent, and then to receive the second e-mail after the set duration.

Have I misunderstood something, or done something wrongly?

Thank you!

Comment: As this is a somewhat exotic topic, you might have more luck with a [proper issue on github](https://github.com/techcrunch/wp-async-task/issues).

Comment: I decided to use `wp_schedule_single_event()` instead. It is also asynchronous and much easier to use (no setup).

Thanks for your response anyway.

Comment: Try this example. https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing-example it add 1 record in debug.log file for evert 5 sec until task complete.

Comment: Super late to the party here, but I think you're misunderstanding the general syntax of async.  It changes slightly from language to language, but calling a 'join' method, universally means 'wait for all async tasks to complete before continuing.'

Comment: Hey, @l_nxy did you found a solution for this issue!?